# Track users in Java SE application with Google Analytics

Tags: java, google-analytics

I have an application which is built in Java SE to store user data after they register and log in to their accounts.

I want to track the users using Google Analytics which we use to track websites visitors.

If this is not possible with GA, how could I track users using the application? I'm interested in gathering their IP address, country, and other info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this java library that allows you to send page and events to your google analytic account:

https://code.google.com/p/jgoogleanalyticstracker/

Here's how to use JGoogleAnalyticsTracker:

```
JGoogleAnalyticsTracker.setProxy(System.getenv("http_proxy")); 
AnalyticsConfigData config = new AnalyticsConfigData("XX-XXXXXXX-X"); 
JGoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker = new JGoogleAnalyticsTracker(config, GoogleAnalyticsVersion.V_4_7_2);
tracker.trackEvent("MyEvent", "MyAction", "Here is a msg");
```

You can also use the one below which is newer and implements the latest google analytics API but I don't like it because of its dependancies on jlogger library:

https://github.com/brsanthu/google-analytics-java

Comment: when i add the library to my project it doenst work .. iam using netbeans and added the first link zip to the project library ,. is that right>?

Comment: import com.brsanthu.googleanalytics.GoogleAnalytics; its not exist maybe iam using the library wrongly :/

Comment: My example was for the 2nd library in the 2nd link. I actually ended up liking the 2nd library better that's why I chose example from that one.

Comment: woo thanks soo much you are the best :D  it works so fine ,, i putted the code into the constructor of my application do you suggest other place to put the code in !!

Comment: It is fun watching it work live in analytics, isn't it? To make sure it doesn't slow down my program startup, I put the above code in a java Thread. That way if the user has a slow internet connection it won't slow down the whole program. p.s. I updated my answer again and put the example library first.

Comment: yea its so exciting :D yea got that ;) thanks so much for your answers it helped me alooooot :D